# Batch SET Variables Not Clearing

Tags: variables, batch-file, if-statement

Okay, so I'm trying to make a batch game with a lot of choices in it. The code for the main action menu section can be found below. All the variables except %c% are set above. Anyways, whenever I get to this section in the batch, I will type in my selection, and it will just reload the menu. Then, the next time I type in my selection, no matter what I put, it will go to the selection that I had typed previously. I have no idea why it does this, because I have the line that says "Set "c=" which should clear it, right? And why does the menu only reload the first time I type in a response?

Any help would be appreciated. If you need more explanation, I'd be happy to give some.

```
:action menu
if "%loc%" NEQ "Falconwood" (
echo Select an option:
echo.
echo 1. Find an Enemy to Fight
echo.
echo 2. View Inventory
echo.
echo 3. Travel
echo.
echo 4. Rest at the Inn
echo.
echo 5. Quit
echo.
echo "%c%"
set "c="
SET /P c=Your Choice: 
if "%c%" == "2" goto :inventory
if "%c%" == "3" goto :travel
if "%c%" == "4" goto :rest
if "%c%" == "5" goto :quitaction
goto :actionmenu )

REM -----HomeMenu-----
if "%loc%"=="Falconwood" (
    if "%house%"=="No" (
        echo Select an option:
        echo.
        echo 1. Buy a house
        echo.
        echo 2. View Inventory
        echo.
        echo 3. Travel
        echo.
        echo 4. Rest at the Inn
        echo.
        echo 5. Quit
        echo.
        set "c="
        SET /P c=Your Choice: 
        if "%c%" == "1" goto :houseshop
        if "%c%" == "2" goto :inventory
        if "%c%" == "3" goto :travel
        if "%c%" == "4" goto :rest
        if "%c%" == "5" goto :quitaction
        goto :actionmenu
    )
    IF "%house%"=="Yes" (
        echo Select an option:
        echo.
        echo 1. Go Home
        echo.
        echo 2. View Inventory
        echo.
        echo 3. Travel
        echo.
        echo 4. Rest at the Inn
        echo.
        echo 5. Quit
        echo.
        set "c="
        SET /P c=Your Choice: 
        REM if "%c%" == 1 goto :houseshop
        if "%c%" == 2 goto :inventory
        if "%c%" == 3 goto :travel
        if "%c%" == 4 goto :rest
        if "%c%" == 5 goto :quitaction
        goto :actionmenu
    )
goto :actionmenu )
```

Comment: Just curious but the closing bracket for this line:

`if "%loc%"=="Falconwood" (`

is supposed to be before or after the last `goto :actionmenu` statement?

Comment: Sorry, it's supposed to be before. I'll edit it.

Comment: Will that really do anything though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMD expands variables when commands are parsed rather than run. So in this case, when you set variables inside the `if` block (commands) and try using them in the same block, it is treated as a single command. This is to say, expansion occurs before the block is executed where variable `c` is replaced by the value it had before the block was executed. Place a `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at the start of your batch file and use `!c!` instead of `%c%` within the block. See [this](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for details.

This may illustrate it better:

```
@echo off
set var1=true
if "%var1%"=="true" (
set var2=false
echo %var2%
)
pause
```

The above code will give you an `ECHO is off.` result for `%var2%`, meaning it wasn't set.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set var1=true
if "%var1%"=="true" (
  set var2=false
  echo !var2!
)
pause
```

The code above will give you `false` for `!var2!`

Comment: One more thing, though. Is there anyway that I can still use !s throughout my batch file, like, while echoing?

Comment: Wherever `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` / `end local` is used in your code, variables which are to be expanded at run time can be accessed (e.g. by echoing) with !'s **not** %'s, but variables which are expanded at parse time can be accessed (e.g. by echoing) by both !'s and %'s

Comment: Thank you very much, Chris. This helps a ton.